# Could GetMember() ever return an empty array for an enum?

Tags: c#, enums, attributes, system.componentmodel

Take a look at this `enum` extension method for getting the [`Description`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute:

```
public static string GetDescription(this Enum enumValue)
{
    var memberInfo = enumValue.GetType().GetMember(enumValue.ToString());

    if (memberInfo.Length < 1)
        return null;

    var attributes = memberInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

    return attributes.Length > 0 ? ((DescriptionAttribute)attributes[0]).Description : enumValue.ToString();
}
```

And an example `enum` with `Description` attributes:

```
public enum Colors
{
    [Description("Navy Blue")]
    Blue,
    [Description("Lime Green")]
    Green
}
```

And finally the usage of the extension method:

```
var blue = Colors.Blue;
Console.WriteLine(blue.GetDescription());
// Console output: Navy Blue
```

My question is, when it comes to `enum`s, is the `if (memberInfo.Length < 1)` check necessary? Would the returned array from `GetMember()` ever be empty for an `enum`? I know you can declare an empty `enum` like this:

```
public enum Colors
{
}
```

But I don't know if you can even create a variable of type `Colors` then...

```
var green = Colors. // What goes here?
```

I would like to remove the `if (memberInfo.Length < 1)` check, but I don't want to do it if it will cause problems later (I can't think of a reason I'd ever need an empty `enum`, but other developers will probably use the `GetDescription()` extension method).

Comment: `Colors green = default` is valid.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria Since enums inherit from some integer type, the default will be the same as 0 and in most cases (when values aren't specified) it will return the first value. The code you posted will equate to Blue

Comment: @Fabulous Not when `Colors` is an empty enum. I just tested it and @AlessandroD'Andria is correct, it throws an `IndexOutOfRangeException` if the `if (memberInfo.Length < 1)` check isn't there. :(

Comment: Equate to `Blue` for first `enum` declaration, but not for second `public enum Colors { }`.

Comment: And so is `Colors green = (Colors)1000`. An enum can contain any value compatible with the base type in .NET

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria Post your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: @LewsTherin I just saw that. I misread the name of the empty one as `Color` so it looked like he was calling the first one again.

Comment: @Fabulous No worries, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a variable of type `Colors` even if no value is defined:

```
public enum Colors { }

var color2 = (Colors)100; // with casting
Colors color2 = default; // default value '0'
```

Comment: The check stays then. Thanks!

Comment: Something often forgotten: even negative integers are valid integers: `(Colors)(-100)` :-)